# Unable to get drawer menu to work in react-native / react-navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm am working on a project and I need to implement a drawer menu/side menu in react-native with react-navigation. I have tried various tutorials online but have been unsuccessful. I have created to the following snack:

https://snack.expo.io/@drc83/drawer-navigation

I just need to get the configuration correct in App.js to get the drawer working. I need the drawer to be accessible only on the MainScreen, and ProductScreen (shouldn't be visible on tour screens or login screens).

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: where do you use `createDrawerNavigator` in Expo?

Comment: Hi I apologise I tried multiple times to get it working without success. I know that createDrawerNavigator needs to be used so had left it in the code.